# Parse data using Powershell and convert to Json

Tags: powershell, oracle-cdc

Background.

i have IBM CDC Replication engine and i need to check subscriptions status by using Zabbix.

Im calling subs status by `cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files\IBM\InfoSphere Data Replication\Management Console\bin\chcclp.exe" -f c:\CDC_Check.txt` where CDC_Check.txt is script for that chcclp CLI

```
//Check the status of all subscriptions

//Source datastore:  ***
//Target datastore:  ***


chcclp session set to cdc;

// Turn on verbose output.
set verbose;

// Setting variables.
set variable name "ACCESS_HOSTNAME" value "";
set variable name "ACCESS_PORT" value "";
set variable name "ACCESS_USERNAME" value "";
set variable name "ACCESS_PASSWORD" value "";
set variable name "SOURCE_DATASTORE" value "";
set variable name "TARGET_DATASTORE" value "";

// Connecting to Access Server.
connect server
    hostname "%ACCESS_HOSTNAME%"
    port "%ACCESS_PORT%"
    username "%ACCESS_USERNAME%"
    password "%ACCESS_PASSWORD%";

// Connecting to the source and target datastores.
connect datastore name "%SOURCE_DATASTORE%";
connect datastore name "%TARGET_DATASTORE%";

// Setting the datastore context.
select datastore name "%SOURCE_DATASTORE%" context source;
select datastore name "%TARGET_DATASTORE%" context target;

// List replication state and latency of all subscriptions.
monitor replication;

// Disconnecting from datastores and Access Server.
disconnect datastore name "%SOURCE_DATASTORE%";
disconnect datastore name "%TARGET_DATASTORE%";

// Disconnect from Access Server and terminate the script.
disconnect server;
exit;
```

and im receiving following result:
[image]
[image]

Im trying to parse Subscription + Status and move it to Json for next integration with zabbix.
Im very new in PS so i still have no normal progress.
I understand idea that i need to capture anything that going under SUBSCRIPTIONS and STATE and write it to Json.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to redirect the output of the app so you can read it in for parsing.

```
cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files\IBM\InfoSphere Data Replication\Management Console\bin\chcclp.exe" -f c:\CDC_Check.txt > C:\temp\file.log
```

Then you can use the get `Get-Content` cmdlet to get it in your console session

```
$fileContent = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\file.log"
```

Once it's in an array you can parse it like so.

```
$i=0
$fileContent | %{
  $i++
  if($_ | Select-String -Pattern "SUBSCRIPTION       STATE" -CaseSensitive){
    $headerIndex = $i
  }
}
$headerIndex += 2 #start of report data to capture
```

This loop continues until it finds the blank line in the output

```
$hashObj= @{}
for ($x = $headerIndex; $fileContent[$x].length -gt 1 ;$x++){ 
  $hashObj.Add("$($fileContent[$x].Substring(0,19).Trim(' '))","$($fileContent[$x].Substring(20,19).Trim(' '))")
}    

#converts your hashtable to json object
$jsonObj = $hashObj | convertto-json
```

Not entirely sure how you need the json formatted but this will be what to expect your output to be similar to

```
{
  "S_ACC_D":  "Mirror Continuous",
  "S_ACC_E":  "Mirror Continuous",
  "S_ACC_A":  "Mirror Continuous",
  "S_ACC_B":  "Mirror Continuous",
  "S_ACC_C":  "Mirror Continuous"
}
```

Comment: Thanx will try to build this.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/CWXqZEs.png
https://i.imgur.com/WDET9xQ.png

A bunch of errors like those appears. I tried  to replace 

($x = $headerIndex; $fileContent[$x].Substring(0,1) -ne " " ;$`x++`) to `x+= 2` coz `HeaderIndex += 2`  and some errors gone.

Comment: @Aleksandr I was using the HeaderIndex var to find the starting place in the output.  Looks like its finding 'subscription' higher in your output causing it to throw errors.  I'll update my post with a better matching for the header of the section you are looking to capture.

Comment: with your new code only one error left https://i.imgur.com/JVW64cS.png
Btw thanx for helping.

Comment: No problem.  The last error is because of the .substring method in the for loop.  Remove that and you should be good to go with no errors.  I updated my post. The JSON should be capturing good values though.

Comment: with latest code there is a lot of errors

https://i.imgur.com/jUhMCub.png

they appearing non-stop

Comment: Your last line in that report must not be a single space.  Try the updated code now.
I added `.length -gt 1` instead of `-ne " "`.  Making a lot of assumptions with the output that you posted from the chcclp.exe app.

Comment: THANX! :) No errors. Now ill try to read it with zabbix and will let you know how its going. Thanx a lot for that part :)